# jq: Insert values according to mappings from external file

Tags: json, mapping, jq

I was wondering how I can complete this task by command line jq. I make up a file with similar nested structure as follows:

```
{
    "item": "item1",
    "features": [
        {
            "feature": "feature_a",
            "value": ""
        },
        {
            "feature": "feature_b",
            "value": ""
        }
     ]
}
```

Now I have another file that maps the `feature` to `value`:

```
feature_a value_1
feature_b value_2
```

So I would like to insert the `value` into the first json file, according to the maps, resulting the following output:

```
{
    "item": "item1";
    "features": [
        {
            "feature": "feature_a",
            "value": "value_1"
        },
        {
            "feature": "feature_b",
            "value": "value_2"
        }
     ]
}
```

How I can achieve above operation by `jq`?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jq: translate array of objects to object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49958035/jq-translate-array-of-objects-to-object)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the text file is in dict.txt and the JSON file is in source.json, the invocation

```
jq -Rs --argfile target source.json dict.txt '
  ([ split("\n")[]
     | select(length>0) 
     | split(" ") 
     | { (.[0]): .[1]} ] 
   | add) as $dict
  | $target
  | .features |= map(.value = $dict[.feature])'
```

would yield the desired output.

The main reason for including `select(length>0)` is to skip any empty strings that might result from using `split("\n")` to split an entire file.

Comment: Thanks! but I always got the error `jq: error: dict/0 is not defined at <top-level>`, I've tried several solutions but cannot fix it...

Comment: I've verified everything using jq 1.4, jq 1.5 and jq 1.6.  Maybe you are not quoting things properly.  I'd suggest putting the jq program into a file, and using the -f option. Also, the error message you give suggests you forgot the dollar sign.

Comment: Thanks `@peek`. It works when I simply move the jq program into a file.